# In Python (2.7), why is os.remove not identical to os.unlink?

Tags: python, python-2.7, object-identity, object-equality

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55) \n[GCC 4.7.2]'
>>> import os
>>> os.remove is os.unlink
False
>>> os.remove == os.unlink
True
```

Why is that? Isn't os.unlink supposed to be an alias of os.remove?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To answer this question we have to dive a bit into the details of how the python interpreter works.  It might be different in other python implementations.

First let's start where the `os.remove` and `os.unlink` functions are defined.  In [Modules/posixmodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Modules/posixmodule.c#L8909) they are registered as:

```
{"unlink",          posix_unlink, METH_VARARGS, posix_unlink__doc__},
{"remove",          posix_unlink, METH_VARARGS, posix_remove__doc__},
```

Note that the function pointers both point to `posix_unlink` in their `ml_meth` member.

For method objects, the `==` equality operator is implemented by `meth_richcompare(...)` in [Objects/methodobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/methodobject.c#L226).

It contains this logic, which explains why the `==` operator returns `True`.

```
a = (PyCFunctionObject *)self;
b = (PyCFunctionObject *)other;
eq = a->m_self == b->m_self;
if (eq)
    eq = a->m_ml->ml_meth == b->m_ml->ml_meth;
```

For built-in functions `m_self` is `NULL` so `eq` starts out `true`.  We then compare the function pointers in `ml_meth` (the same `posix_unlink` referenced from the struct above) and since they match `eq` remains `true`.  The end result is that python returns `True`.

The `is` operator is simpler and stricter.  The `is` operator only compares the `PyCFunctionObj*` pointers.  They will be different -- they came from different structs and are distinct objects, so the `is` operator will return `False`.

The rationale is likely that they are separate functions objects (recall their docstrings are different) but they point to the same implementation, so the difference in behavior between `is` and `==` is justifiable.

`is` brings a stronger guarantee, and is meant to be fast and cheap (a pointer comparison, essentially).  The `==` operator inspects the object and returns `True` when its content matches.  In this context, the function pointer is the content.