# Python exception - how does the args attribute get automatically set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

Suppose I define the following exception:

```
>>> class MyError(Exception):
...     def __init__(self, arg1):
...         pass
```

Then I instantiate the class to create an exception object:

```
>>> e = MyError('abc')
>>> e.args
('abc',)
```

Here how is the `args` attribute getting set? (In the `__init__`, I am doing nothing.)

Comment: This attribute is described in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/exceptions.html#BaseException.args
It doesn't answer the question why is it assigned even with overwritten constructor though

Answer (score 9):

`args` is implemented as a data descriptor with `__get__` and `__set__` methods.

This takes place inside `BaseException.__new__` like @bakatrouble mentioned. Among other things, what happens inside `BaseException.__new__` is roughly like the Python code below:

```
class BaseException:
    def __new__(cls, *args): 
        # self = create object of type cls
        self.args = args  # This calls: BaseException.args.__set__(self, args) 
        ...
        return self
```

In C code of *Python 3.7.0 alpha 1*, the above Python code looks like this *(inspect Python's C code for any past or future differences)*:

```
BaseException_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    # other things omitted... 
    self = (PyBaseExceptionObject *)type->tp_alloc(type, 0);
    # many things follow... 
    if (args) {
        self->args = args;
        Py_INCREF(args);
        return (PyObject *)self;

    }
    # many more things follow
}
```

Experimenting interactively:

```
>>> e = Exception('aaa')
>>> e
Exception('aaa',)
```

---

```
>>> BaseException.args.__set__(e, ('bbb',))
>>> e
Exception('bbb',)
>>> BaseException.args.__get__(e)
('bbb',)
```

Hence, the magical inspiration of `args` that makes your eyes look heavenward takes place in `BaseException.__new__`, when an object of `BaseException` or any of its sub-classes is created.

Comment: The `Exception` class also has `__new__` method. Going by the inheritance hierarchy, shouldn't this method be called instead of `BaseException.__new__`?

Comment: @Deb Essentially all exception classes use the same methods of `BaseException` including `__init__` and `__new__` . `Exception` extends `BaseException` and if you look at the [C source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/exceptions.c#L452) specifically inside the macro you'll notice that the macro `SimpleExtendsException` uses both`BaseException_new` and `BaseException_init`. Since I'm not a C wizard, I welcome any verification or correction from other members. But to me, this is obviously the case with 99% certainty.

Comment: @Deb Note if you check `BaseException.__dict__['__new__'] is Exception.__dict__['__new__']` in Python, this is `False`, but they could be the same! Just like the case for [`os.unlik` and `os.remove`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241091/in-python-2-7-why-is-os-remove-not-identical-to-os-unlink).

Answer (score 1):

It is being set in the `BaseException.__new__()` method, which could be seen here: [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3a7f03584ab75afbf5507970711c87042e423bb4/Objects/exceptions.c#L45)

Note: in Python 2.7 it is being set in the `BaseException.__init__()` method, so the override makes `.args` dict always empty (not sure if pointing to the correct line): [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a850ef698e55d07173051747e96207496c6f1bdb/Objects/exceptions.c#L62)

Comment: @Deb when you input `e = MyError('abc')`, the inheritance translates `Exception('abc')`

Comment: @PRMoureu No, superclass constructor should be called explicitely if overwritten. For that reason it doesn't work in Python 2.7 because `args` attribute is being set in the constructor, not in the `__new__()` method.

Comment: @PRMoureu In this aspect behavior is the same. If you want overwritten superclass method to be executed, you should call it explicitely. But the `__new__()` method has some magic in it which I don't fully understand yet... https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__